# What libraries do I need in what scope to develop in Scala

Tags: scala, classpath

I'm trying to figure out what I need on the classpath and in what scope to be able to compile and run a scala application.

I have the following libraries (jars) and have made a guess and what scope I need them in:

- jline - no idea on this one
- scala-compiler - presumably only required to compile so don't need to be on the classpath at all
- scala-continuations
- scala-library - will need this on the compile classpath
- scalap - no idea on this one
- scala-parser-combinators - no idea on this one
- scal-reflect - if using reflection this will need to be on the compile classpath
- scala-swing - don't need swing so don't need this
- scala-xml - if using the XML features of scala this will need to be on the compile classpath?

Am I correct?

NOTE: I have to reference these manually due to restrictions in the company I work in - so I can't use an off-the-shelf solution you can find via google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need *anything* in your classpath to run scala programs. Just a JVM:

```
$ cat Main.scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) =
    System.out.println(1)
}
$ scalac Main.scala
$ java Main
1
```

Most programs require the standard library (hard to do much without functions and tuples, hum hum java...), but everything else you cited is highly optional.

Comment: In order to use anything useful I'd need the standard library for collections etc...right?